# Get html data in post method in netsuite suitelet

Tags: netsuite

I have a suitelet in which in run html code having an html table. I have given checkbox to the table. I wanted to retrieve number of lines and values in table which are checked after I click Submit on Suitelet. However, I only get one value of checkbox and not how many lines I have set the checkbox true.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="select-items" name="selectitem" id="selectitem">
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: I think your name parameter needs to be an indexed name like: selectitem[0] etc

Comment: @Coldstar No. this didn't help